# Bootstrap tabbed navigation - multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap tabbed navigation, I have multiple submit buttons (one for each tab). On submit, the page submits (I am not using ajax) and comes back to the same tab. However, before it comes back to the tab which has submitted the page, for a moment, the first tab appears (active tab) and then the current tab. On a local environment, this can not noticed but in production environment, this can be easily noticed.

Here is the sample code snippet. Any inputs please?

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs id='tabviewid'>
        <li class=" active "><a href="#tab1 " data-toggle="tab ">Tab1</a></li>
        <li class="active "><a href="#tab2 " data-toggle="tab ">Tab2</a></li>
  </ul>            
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 tab-content ">        
        <div class="tab-pane active " id="tab1 ">
            {{Form::open(array('url' => 'Home','class' => 'form-horizontal'))}}
  <div>
                    {{Form::submit('Create',array('class' => 'btn  btn-sm btn-primary openbutton', 'id' => 'btnCreate', 'name' => 'Create'));}}
                </div>
            {{Form::close()}}
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2 ">
            {{Form::open(array('url' => 'Home','class' => 'form-horizontal'))}}
                <div>
                    {{Form::submit('Update',array('class' => 'btn  btn-sm btn-primary openbutton', 'id' => 'btnUpdate', 'name' => 'Update'));}}
                </div>
            {{Form::close()}}
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because the tab pane has the `active` attribute and you're probably using javascript to remove it and add it to the other tab (which occurs after the page has already loaded). Add `active` to tab2 instead of tab1 **using PHP** and tab1 won't be shown initially.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove class "active" in

   ```
   <div class="tab-pane active " id="tab1 ">
   ```
2. In controller have action "Home"

   ```
   public function postHome(){
       ...
       $tab = Input::get("Create") ? "tab1" : "tab2";
       return Redirect::back()->with("active", $tab);
   }
   ```
3. In your view

   ```
   $active = Session::get("active"); // Can put in controller or view
   ...
   <div class="tab-pane {{$active == "tab1" ? "active" : ""}} " id="tab1 ">
   ...
   <div class="tab-pane {{$active == "tab2" ? "active" : ""}} " id="tab2 ">
   ```